# Stand development and push processing

Tags: film, developing, push-processing

I've been doing some reading on [stand development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand_development), I'm curious if adding more rodinal developer (1:50 instead of 1:100) or add additional agitation/ time to push film? Just wondering how much more developer I would need to push, say, Ilford hp5 120mm +2 stops?

Comment: I have nothing useful to add to this conversation, but I'm glad that in this age of DSLRs, people are documenting their knowledge of the dying art of film processing. Kudos, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You usually push by keeping the film longer in developer or using a different temperature for the developer. I haven't yet heard of anyone using more concentrated developer for pushing.

**You also have to consider what developer you use.** Concentrations and times might vary from one developer to another.

[Ilford official website - Push Processing](http://www.ilfordphoto.com/applications/page.asp?n=88):

> It is normal to use an active, “speed-enhancing” developer for push processing, such as ILFORD Microphen or ILFORD Ilfotec DD-X, and also to develop for a longer time or at a higher temperature than normal; see the fact sheets for individual ILFORD films or the ILFORD Film Processing Chart for development time guidelines.

Also, 
[Ilford official website - Application sheet: Push processing](http://www.ilfordphoto.com/Webfiles/20062102012331472.pdf):

> Your choice of developer will influence the quality of your image as
>   much as your choice of film. Most developers can be used for push
>   processing, but a few, such as PERCEPTOL, are unsuitable as they lower
>   film speed in order to obtain the finest grain. The best push
>   processing developers, such as MICROPHEN and ILFOTEC DD–X, give a
>   small increase in film speed at normal contrast.

In any case, you have to check the fact sheets for both film **and** developer before starting developing the film, no matter you do a normal development or you want to push.

Comment: that is all good information, thanks for posting. Stand developer is a little different way of developing. the process uses a highly diluted developer (1:100) and a very long development time (1 hour+). with no agitation. this allows the shadows to develop, giving a lower contrast image and better shadow detail.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode It doesn't matter, the point of push or pull processing is that you alter the time to get the effect.  The answer is right to check the film and developer to see how to push it. Whenever I push, I always increase the time and keep the same amount of agitation.

Comment: @SailorCire, You would be absolutely correct for any standard development process. there are some great resources online for stand development. it is accomplished by no agitation and completely exhausting the chemical in the process. When used with certain developers like Accufine, Rodinol, hc-110, and Pyro using 1:100 dilution and dev times around 2 hrs, there is a reduction of grain (especially with the pyro), increase dynamic range, and some other qualities..

Comment: in this case increasing the time wouldn't do much because the solution has been exhausted by then. the only way to increase the development is by increasing the amount of developer from the start.